# Custom UIMenuController using button event error There can only be one UIMenuController instance

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, copy-paste, uimenucontroller

I create a button that when you hold, it will show the standard ios menu button for pasting a text, but I'm getting an error saying `There can only be one UIMenuController instance.` when I hold the button 2 times, how can I fix this?

Here is my code

```swift
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.configureView()
}
    
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    self.configureView()
}

private func configureView() {
    guard let view = self.loadViewFromNib(nibName: "CustomView") else { return }
    view.frame = self.bounds
    self.addSubview(view)
        
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(holdButton), for: .touchDown)
}

@objc func holdButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let menuController = UIMenuController()
    menuController.setTargetRect(sender.frame, in: charTextField)
    menuController.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
}
```

Also, how can I listen to the user when he clicked the `paste` button?

I want it to call this function when he clicked `paste`.

```swift
func pasteClick() {
    print("pasted", clipboardString())
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the default singleton instance provided (`.shared`) by `UIMenuController` instead of creating an instance of your own.

```
@objc func holdButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UIMenuController.shared.setTargetRect(sender.frame, in: charTextField)
    UIMenuController.shared.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
}
```

Quoting from [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenucontroller):

> The singleton UIMenuController instance is referred to as the editing
> menu.....